# Running Application at StartUp

Tags: c#, startup, launching-application

Hi i am running `windows 7 64 bit`.

I made an application that uses `sql lite database` and to do operation application has `application manifist` file to `require admin`.

Now issue is that i need to run this application when ever windows starts up it should run after login.

now i tried two approaches

1.Writing Registry `Run`

2.Creating ShortCut to StartUp Folder.

when ever i restart my application it does not start up.even if i get the path from `regedit` or startup shortcut is clicked the application starts up.

What is the Issue?

One thing i noticed that if application does not requires Admin permission then it launches. but in that case database exception occurs`"Attempt to write a read only database"`

but launching with admin rights Works on `WinXP`

Comment: Did it work before on a 64 bit system?

Comment: This is spiraling out of control.  Move the database file to a folder that you have write access to.  Like the user's AppData folder.  Use Environment.GetFolderPath() to find it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check the permissions of the directory containing the sqlite db ? the directory should be write enabled